# Not able to play the video

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I want to download the video from the web and write that file into the local folder . I have done following code for this:

```
     if(videoUrl!=Nil)
        {
            if(moviePlayer==NULL)
            {

                NSString *newPath = @"/Users/theuser/Desktop/data/b.m3u8";
                NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/bipbopall.m3u8"]];
                NSLog(@"data=%@",videoData);
                [videoData writeToFile:newPath atomically:YES];
            }

        }
```

I am retrieving the video in same application . I have following code for that:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
   // NSString *directory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *newPath = @"/Users/theuser/Desktop/data/b.m3u8";//[directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"myMovie.m3u8"];
    NSLog(@"path=%@",newPath);
    moviePlayerController=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath isDirectory:NO]];
    moviePlayerController.scalingMode=MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    moviePlayerController.view.frame=CGRectMake(320,200,320,200);
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
    [moviePlayerController play];
    NSLog(@"played");

}
```

But i am getting the following exception :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'An AVPlayerItem cannot be associated with more than one instance of AVPlayer'
```

Why this is happening ?

Comment: Maybe this will help : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10830550/986169

Comment: Accept my previous answer (that lead you to this question) if you want me to help.

Comment: Your previous question asked why saving a url to a movie did not cache the movie. I said it is because it is not downloading the movie. Now your next question is how to download a movie. What kind of answer were you looking for, and how can you say it didn't help you? I'm not sure but I think I have 100% acceptance rating because I have 100% good answers. If your question is good you will get a very good answer. We help you if we feel we can get something in return. Your question does not provide us with any professional stimulation so you need to offer something else - like nice shiny points

Comment: you can't play m3u8 files locally.